# angular 2: queryParams onInit

Tags: angular

I'm currently having some problems with the queryParams of an ActivatedRoute. I'm trying to achieve a system where you can call any url with the queryParams = "?token=1234". If this param is provided the AppComponent will use this token to authenticate the user.

The reason for this is that a user will be authenticated within a different application, which will receive a token and forward it to the angular application.

So, in my AppComponent I have the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this._route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        if (queryParams['token'] != null) {
            let data;
            this._staffService.getStaffFromToken(queryParams['token']).subscribe(
                (response: any) => data = response,
                (error: Error) => console.error(error),
                () => {
                    if (data.token != null) {
                        this._staffService.setLoggedInStaff(data.staff);
                        this.processLogin();
                    } else {
                        this._router.navigateByUrl('/login');
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {
            if (this._staffService.getLoggedInStaff() != null) {
                this.processLogin();
            } else {
                this._router.navigateByUrl('/login');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I totally understand the idea of being able to subscribe to these params since it's a SPA and the params might change while using the application.

However, when I go to the following url: http://localhost:4200?token=1234 it navigates immediately to /login. For some reason, when ngOnInit is being called, it doesn't detect the queryParam immediately. When I add a debounceTime of 500 to queryParams, it does work properly but isn't a good solution in my opinion.

Does anyone have some advice? I tried different things but I keep having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to place your code in `ngOnChanges()` and review the ng2 [Lifecycle](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

Answer (score 0):

When using observable you can't write synchronous code.

Try this.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
   const token = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['token'];
   Your code ...
}
```